# Partial payment option

Tags: payment, partial-payments

Please help me in pay some amount by credit card and remaining by cash on delivery option in magento. Like, if product price is 100$, then we can define in admin panel that 60$ will be paid by credit card and rest 40$ will be paid by cash on delivery option.

Comment: Default Magento does not provide dividing the order amount into parts and charges the whole amount all together only. So if the customer's credit card does not have sufficient balance, it won't complete the payment and order.

But Magento Partial Payment Extension by Milople Provides a facility where it is possible to divide the order in parts. User can pay the first payment as down payment when they place the order and later can pay the remaining balance with different or same credit card.

This may fulfill your requirements.